# Use string.Contains() with switch()

Tags: c#, string, if-statement, switch-statement, contains

I'm doing an C# app where I use

```
if ((message.Contains("test")))
{
   Console.WriteLine("yes");
} else if ((message.Contains("test2"))) {
   Console.WriteLine("yes for test2");
}
```

There would be any way to change to `switch()` the `if()` statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the check at first and then use the switch as you like.

For example:

```
string str = "parameter"; // test1..test2..test3....

if (!message.Contains(str)) return ;
```

Then

```
switch(str)
{
  case "test1" : {} break;
  case "test2" : {} break;
  default : {} break;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this answer.

Comment: In the scenario of str = "test1,test2"; case "test1" will not work.

Answer (score 160):

Correct final syntax for [Mr. C]s answer.

With the release of VS2017RC and its C#7 support it works this way:

```
switch(message)
{
    case string a when a.Contains("test2"): return "no";
    case string b when b.Contains("test"): return "yes";
}
```

You should take care of the case ordering as the first match will be picked. That's why "test2" is placed prior to test.

Comment: +1 This works perfectly now.  And to anyone wondering you can access the value of the case via the "x" variable in this scenario.

Comment: Also, you can use any var name-except-the one in the switch statement to evaluate. Then, you can refer to the original variable/expression in the code that follows.

Comment: @Patrick, can you clarify what you mean by the "x" variable? Sorry I'm sure it's obvious.

Comment: I feel so dumb asking about this simple answer, but isn't "break" also mandatory in C# case statements?

Comment: In case statements you can leave the break if you use return.

Comment: I believe this should be marked the answer.

Answer (score 39):

This will work in C# 8 using a switch expresion

```
var message = "Some test message";

message = message switch
{
    string a when a.Contains("test") => "yes",
    string b when b.Contains("test2") => "yes for test2",
    _ => "nothing to say"
};
```

For further references
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression

Comment: I find switch expressions a very strange syntax that is hard to remember.  Always find myself looking it up if I haven't used it in a few months...

Comment: it harder to write but easier to read.. Worth the effort.

Answer (score 36):

Nope, switch statement requires compile time constants. The statement `message.Contains("test")` can evaluate true or false depending on the message so it is not a constant thus cannot be used as a 'case' for switch statement.

Comment: So I only can use `if()`? That's pretty messy :(

Comment: @zad0xsis: Do you have a lot of these? If so, you could potentially abstract the idea somewhat...

Comment: yeah I've got a lot of `if()` :(

Comment: It's worth noting - this will change with C# 7. Patterns can be used in case clauses. As of this writing, this feature is available in Visual Studio 15 Preview 4. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/

Answer (score 34):

If you just want to use `switch/case`, you can do something like this, pseudo-code:

```
    string message = "test of mine";
    string[] keys = new string[] {"test2",  "test"  };

    string sKeyResult = keys.FirstOrDefault<string>(s=>message.Contains(s));

    switch (sKeyResult)
    {
        case "test":
            Console.WriteLine("yes for test");
            break;
        case "test2":
            Console.WriteLine("yes for test2");
            break;
    }
```

But if the quantity of keys is a big, you can just replace it with dictionary, like this:

```
static Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string message = "test of mine";      

    // this happens only once, during initialization, this is just sample code
    dict.Add("test", "yes");
    dict.Add("test2", "yes2"); 


    string sKeyResult = dict.Keys.FirstOrDefault<string>(s=>message.Contains(s));

    Console.WriteLine(dict[sKeyResult]); //or `TryGetValue`... 
 }
```

Comment: I removed `<string>` from `string sKeyResult = keys.FirstOrDefault<string>(s=>message.Contains(s));` and still works fine.

Comment: This is truly thinking outside the box.  Nice!

Answer (score 24):

Simple yet efficient with c#

```
 string sri = "Naveen";
    switch (sri)
    {
        case var s when sri.Contains("ee"):
           Console.WriteLine("oops! worked...");
        break;
        case var s when sri.Contains("same"):
           Console.WriteLine("oops! Not found...");
        break;
    }
```

Comment: If you don't need the value of `var s` (as you don't in your example) you can use `var _` to discard it.

Comment: Similarly to the answer above when you don't need the value of `var s`, you can use `not null` to discard it.

Answer (score 7):

```
string message = "This is test1";
string[] switchStrings = { "TEST1", "TEST2" };
switch (switchStrings.FirstOrDefault<string>(s => message.ToUpper().Contains(s)))
{
    case "TEST1":
        //Do work
        break;
    case "TEST2":
        //Do work
        break;
    default:
        //Do work
        break; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Faced with this issue when determining an environment, I came up with the following one-liner:

```
string ActiveEnvironment = localEnv.Contains("LIVE") ? "LIVE" : (localEnv.Contains("TEST") ? "TEST" : (localEnv.Contains("LOCAL") ? "LOCAL" : null));
```

That way, if it can't find anything in the provided string that matches the "switch" conditions, it gives up and returns `null`. This could easily be amended to return a different value.

It's not *strictly* a switch, more a cascading if statement but it's neat and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Some custom swtich can be created like this. Allows multiple case execution as well

```
public class ContainsSwitch
{

    List<ContainsSwitch> actionList = new List<ContainsSwitch>();
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public Action Action { get; set; }
    public bool SingleCaseExecution { get; set; }
    public void Perform( string target)
    {
        foreach (ContainsSwitch act in actionList)
        {
            if (target.Contains(act.Value))
            {
                act.Action();
                if(SingleCaseExecution)
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    public void AddCase(string value, Action act)
    {
        actionList.Add(new ContainsSwitch() { Action = act, Value = value });
    }
}
```

Call like this

```
string m = "abc";
ContainsSwitch switchAction = new ContainsSwitch();
switchAction.SingleCaseExecution = true;
switchAction.AddCase("a", delegate() { Console.WriteLine("matched a"); });
switchAction.AddCase("d", delegate() { Console.WriteLine("matched d"); });
switchAction.AddCase("a", delegate() { Console.WriteLine("matched a"); });

switchAction.Perform(m);
```

Answer (score 1):

Stegmenn nalied it for me, but I had one change for when you have an IEnumerable instead of a `string = message` like in his example.

```
private static string GetRoles(IEnumerable<External.Role> roles)
{
    string[] switchStrings = { "Staff", "Board Member" };
    switch (switchStrings.FirstOrDefault<string>(s => roles.Select(t => t.RoleName).Contains(s)))
    {
        case "Staff":
            roleNameValues += "Staff,";
            break;
        case "Board Member":
            roleNameValues += "Director,";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work in C# 7. As of this writing, it has yet to be released. But **if I understand this correctly**, this code will work.

```
switch(message)
{
    case Contains("test"):
        Console.WriteLine("yes");
        break;
    case Contains("test2"):
        Console.WriteLine("yes for test2");
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("No matches found!");
}
```

Source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/

Comment: No, this does not work. `Contains does not exist in the current context.`

Comment: I cannot see your example on the link provided.

Comment: Does not work, you should test it first before sharing your answer. See [Lakedaimon's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41428406/3009574) for the correct syntax.

Comment: This is pretty close.  Mr. C is correct in his answer.  "This will work in C# 7"  The syntax for this to work is slightly off though... Review Lakedaimon's answer for correct syntax.

Answer (score -6):

```
switch(message)
{
  case "test":
    Console.WriteLine("yes");
    break;                
  default:
    if (Contains("test2")) {
      Console.WriteLine("yes for test2");
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. For a useful answer explain why this is an answer to the question.

Comment: in C# switch condition is not powerful as KOTLIN so if you want to implement String.contains() in condition state of switch I think we have to separate our condition in default part