# How to use .Contains() in a switch statement in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to use the Contains() in a switch statement in C# but I don't know how. If you don't understand me, I'll show you the code so maybe you'll understand I guess.

Code I want to work:

```cs
public void Read(string text)
{
    switch (text.ToLower().Contains())
    {
        case "read":
            MessageBox.Show(text);
            break;
        case "not":
            MessageBox.Show(text);
            break;
    }
}
```

The upper code is the one I've attempted, but it doesn't work. So how can I use a function in a switch statement. I could use `else if`s but I want to use it in a switch statement.

Comment: Use `if` ... `else if`

Comment: @Axyclez You seem dissatisfied with the suggestions. Perhaps you could instead elaborate why you want to use a `switch` statement instead of `if {} else if {}`?

Comment: @Axyclez Any differences in performance between `switch` and `if` are negligible and not worth considering.

Comment: @Axyclez I don't think people say your code is messy because you don't use a switch statement. You might want them to elaborate on that so you can focus on what matters to write better code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use string.Contains() with switch()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175580/use-string-contains-with-switch)

Comment: @sous2817 it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though if there are just 2cases then you shoul always goes with if , but still if you wana do with switch , you can do with pattern matching. you may need C# 7.0 for this I think

```
       public static void Read(string text)
    {
        switch (text)
        {
            case var read when text.ToLower().Contains("read"):
                MessageBox.Show(text);
                break;
            case var nott when text.ToLower().Contains("not"):
                MessageBox.Show(text);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Am not saying my solution is perfect. Am saying yes its possible with switch

Answer (score 1):

```
public void Read(string text)
{
  switch (text)
  {
    case string a when test.ToLower().Contains("read"):
      MessageBox.Show(text);
      break;
    case string b when test.ToLower().Contains("not"):
      MessageBox.Show(text);
      break;
  }
}
```

Also, the answer is here on how to use string.Contains() method with switch statement. [Use string.Contains() with switch()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175580/use-string-contains-with-switch)

Answer (score 0):

`Contains()` function can not be used like this inside switch statement because it will either return `true` or `false` while switch statement applies to variables returning random cases like `1,2,3` , for your problem it will be best to use 'if else' instead.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, both `case`s are *equal*: either text contains `"read"` or `"not"` we should do the same: show the `"text`"

I suggest get rid of `switch` and have a single `if`:

```
using System.Linq; // to query with any

...

public void Read(string text) {
  // public method arguments validation
  if (null == text)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(text));

  string[] words = new string[] {"read", "not"};

  // ToLower() is a bad practice: 
  // - it may occure that we don't have to process the entire text
  // - StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase is more readable
  // - words doesn't have to lowercase words only   
  if (words.Any(word => text.Contains(word, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
    MessageBox.Show(text);
}
```